# How do I enter rotation values in radians?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I personally prefer to use radians instead of degrees whenever possible, is just more comfortable to me. Is there any way to set blenders UI in a way where I never have to use degrees ever again and just interact with blender using radians?

I put this image up as an example, i'd just be really cool to be able to see rotation values as radians. Just a transform node in the geometry node system.

It'd be even cooler to see it as multiples of pi(not just input it as multiples of pi), but maybe that is asking for too much.

[image: geometry nodes screenshot]

Comment: I don't get why this got closed. The chosen duplicate matches very poorly and does not answer this question fully, since there are more ways to use different units than to set them as scene units - you can enter a number followed by r in any angle input field to use radians.

Comment: This a peculiar feature of Geometry Nodes, Blender 3.0a. _Typing_ into the field converts from degrees to radians. _Feeding_ the field from, say, a _Combine XYZ_, or an input piped out to the modifer, accepts radians directly. I would hope for a revision to consistency, in time.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys The OP might have mistakenly accepted the duplicate unaware of its effects. Reopened now, answer away

Answer (score 3):

You can use radians in a few different ways:

- Set scene angle units to radians in the Scene tab, Properties editor under units:

[image]

- Or you could leave default degrees, but specify that you are entering radians in any angle input field following the number with "r":

[image]

This does not seem to work correctly with radians set as scene units for some reason currently.

- Input fields also accept functions degrees() or radians(), but that's probably too much typing.
- if you wanted to use radians with rotate operator's numerical input, you also can do that after entering advanced input mode with <kbd>Numpad *</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easy, actually, by changing unit system in the Scene properties:

[image]

Just chose *Rotation* - *Radians* in the **Units** section.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know, typing `pi` into an input field will get the value of **PI** to that input. So using the formula `deg_value= radians_value * 180 * 1 / pi`, I suggest you to just add a few more nodes to your setup :

**1-** A **Math node set to multiply**. The top value will be `180` and the bottom socket would be the value of your angle in radians

**2-** Plug the output of that node to a second **Math node set to multiply**. The other value would be `1/180`

After doing so, you can plug the output of the last node to where you want to input you angle.